# Convert openCV image to point cloud

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to convert an OpenCV image to a point cloud (the actual goal is to build a text output of the ones in the point cloud) however I couldn't find the correct path to follow.

```
        A = cv2.imread(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(source_folder, file)))
        #print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_folder, file)))
        B = cv2.cvtColor(A, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ...
        core_r = np.r_['r', [-1, 1]]
        core_c = np.r_['c', [-1, 1]]
        I1 = cv2.filter2D(H, -1, kernel=np.float32(core_r))
        I2 = cv2.filter2D(H, -1, kernel=np.float32(core_c))
        K = cv2.bitwise_and(A, H, mask=C[1])
```

I do several masking here (skipped most for simplicity) on the original image. I want to build a point cloud of the resulting K. As a result of the masking and other operations, all points are either white or black in K.

However, it seems to be a 512x512x3 numpy array (thus,numpy.savetxt doesnt work). How could I save it in a point cloud format 1-0 in a 512x512 matrix?

Adding an example K for your concern [example K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lImy.jpg) .. I can save them as jpg or png with matplotlib or cv2 without any problem.

Thanks for your support in advance

Comment: I see nothing that would turn your image into a point cloud. how are you trying to achieve that? and why do you think that'll work, given just a plain picture?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. 'That' is the core of my question really. How could I move from here to a point cloud :) Tried several things without any success

Comment: please provide a picture out of which you realistically expect to "make" a point cloud. please educate yourself on "multiple view geometry", specifically stereo vision and disparity maps, as well as "structure from motion".